# Fast way to summarize a data frame across columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, bioinformatics, summarize

I have this `data.frame` of five possible `character` states (`genotypes`):

```
genotypes <- c("0/0","1/1","0/1","1/0","./.")
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i)
  matrix(sample(genotypes, 30, replace = T), nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("V", 1:30))))) %>%
  data.frame()
```

And I wan to summarize each row into how many I have of each:

- `ref.hom` (`0/0`)
- `alt.hom` (`1/1`)
- `het` (`0/1` or `1/0`)
- `na` (`./.`)

This seems rather slow:

```
sum.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  data.frame(ref.hom = length(which(df[i,] == "0/0")),
             alt.hom = length(which(df[i,] == "1/1")),
             het = length(which(df[i,] == "0/1") | which(df[i,] == "1/0")),
             na = length(which(df[i,] == "./.")))
}))
```

Any more efficient, perhaps `dplyr` based way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can try:

```
df %>%
 transmute(ref.hom = rowSums(. == "0/0"),
           alt.hom = rowSums(. == "1/1"),
           het = rowSums(. == "0/1") + rowSums(. == "1/0"),
           na = rowSums(. == "./."))

    ref.hom alt.hom het na
1         4      11   9  6
2         5       2  20  3
3         3      11  10  6
4         5       5  15  5
5         5       4  17  4
6         3       8  13  6
7         6       8  11  5
8         4       8  11  7
9         6       6  14  4
10       14       8   5  3
```

Comment: hi, how can it be faster with the mutate than without?

Comment: @Johannes Stötzer a good point. I confused it with a different situation.

Answer (score 4):

For genotyping data, I would use `setDT()`. You will save considerable amount of RAM.

```
library(data.table)
df$key <- 1:nrow(df)
df <- melt(setDT(df),id.vars = "key")
table(df$key, df$value) 

 # > head(table(df$key, df$value))
 #
 #   ./. 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/1
 # 1   6   6   4   7   7
 # 2   6   3   8   5   8
 # 3   7   3   5   5  10
 # 4   4   8   1   7  10
 # 5   5   9   4   3   9
 # 6   9   2   6   8   5
# and
table(df$value)
# > table(df$value)
# ./. 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/1 
# 620 581 601 584 614
```

Execution time check:

```
> time.taken.DT
Time difference of 0.005386114 secs
> time.taken.dplyr
Time difference of 0.08833909 secs
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `setDT()` is from the *data.table* package so people aren't wondering where it suddenly popped up from.

Comment: Also, if you're taking advantage of data.table, you could use the much more efficient `by=` grouping instead.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `apply` with `table` which will return count of all possible levels in each row.

```
output <- t(apply(df, 1, table))
output

#     ./. 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/1
#[1,]   7   8   4   3   8
#[2,]   5   7   4   9   5
#[3,]   6   5   6   5   8
#[4,]   4   7   9   6   4
#[5,]   6   5   6   5   8
#[6,]   8   8   2   7   5
#....
```

Later if you need you can combine the columns into one level `output[, 3] + output[, 4]`.

---

Another option would be to `gather` the data into long format and `count`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -row) %>%
  count(row, value)
  #If needed
  #tidyr::spread(value, n)
```